# can't split that string with return character

Tags: javascript

I have res from JSON with that string :

```
"nID_ServiceData
0-151975019"
```

this string with `<br>`, or return character...

when i try to split this:

```
var x=     "nID_ServiceData
           0-151975019";
var y = x.split(' ');
```

it became `["nID_ServiceData↵0-151975019"]`, so I try again :

```
y.split('↵');
```

but again I have - `["nID_ServiceData↵0-151975019"]`.
Where I make mistake?

Comment: Your quoted code generates a syntax error. Quote your real code, simplified but not made incorrect.

Comment: Try using x.split('\n') or x.split('\r\n')

Comment: @Paul hooray! it works, thx a lot!

Comment: @Jonny I'm glad! You should accept one of the answers which provides a more detailed and useful explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *return character* is represented as `\n` in javascript, so `x.split("\n");` should work.

Answer (score 2):

`var y = x.split(' ');` is trying to split on a **space**, but your string has a newline (`\n`). Split on a newline, instead of a space.

```
var x = "nID_ServiceData\n0-151975019";
var y = x.split("\n");
```

If the newline *might* be a CRLF combination (`\r\n`) but may not (just `\n`), you can use a regular expression to do the split:

```
var x = "nID_ServiceData\n0-151975019";
var y = x.split(/\r?\n/);
```